# cursor.lastrowid returning 0, MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Im very new to mySQL and I'm trying to get the lastrowid but in the following code, lastrowid only returns 0. What am I doing wrong?

```
cursor.execute(
    "INSERT INTO ksgame (white, status, time, rated, white_rating) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",
    (session["username"], "searching", time, rated, rating),
)
# Adding the link to the db
cursor.execute(
    "UPDATE ksgame SET site = %s WHERE game_id = %s",
    (
        "http://127.0.0.1:5000/play/" + str(cursor.lastrowid),
        cursor.lastrowid,
    ),
)
# Commiting changes
db.commit()
# Setting a boolean to keep track of black player's presence
black_player = False

# As long as black player is not here
times = 0

while not black_player:
    times += 1
    # Keep looking if any joined
    # -------------Here it returns 0 ---------------------------------------------
    print(cursor.lastrowid)
    cursor.execute(
        "SELECT black FROM ksgame WHERE game_id = %s", (cursor.lastrowid,)
    )
    black = cursor.fetchall()
    black = [dict(row) for row in black]
    if times == 1000:
        print(cursor.fetchall())
        times = 0
    cursor.reset()
    # If a black player has joined
    if black["black"] != None:
        # Set black_player boolean to true to stop the wait
        black_player = True
```

I tried to truncate the db and try again, I keep getting the same problem and because of a non existent row id, I keep getting and error at the while loop.

EDIT- Didn't include error, so here it is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/KnightStable/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/KnightStable/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/KnightStable/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/KnightStable/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/home/KnightStable/mysite/knightstable/game/routes.py", line 280, in play
    black = [dict(row) for row in black]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Im pretty sure im getting this error because the row id is wrong

Comment: You need to show the error. Your question is confused because you tell us that it always returns `0` and then, at the end, apparently you're just getting errors. That doesn't make sense. Which is it?

Comment: @roganjosh sorry for not including the error, i'll edit the post and include it

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-lastrowid.html) for this is somewhat wooly.

It states:

> The lastrowid property is like the mysql_insert_id() C API function; see mysql_insert_id().

If we go there, it states:

> Returns the value generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous INSERT or UPDATE statement

Followed by:

> The return value of mysql_insert_id() is always zero unless explicitly updated under one of the following conditions:

However, if you search for "update", the only condition seems to be an upsert:

> When called after an INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement:

That's problematic in itself, but ok (I guess?). You're not doing an upsert, so perhaps it will just sit at `0`.

---

```
black = cursor.fetchall()
black = [dict(row) for row in black]
```

is a different issue. You just didn't get any results back so you can't iterate the cursor. But... that should be an empty iterator from the start, so you should get an empty list and not an error. I suspect something is missing. You're doing stuff like this:

```
if times == 1000:
    print(cursor.fetchall())
```

Why? You already exhausted the generator in `black = cursor.fetchall()` so it's highly likely you did that somewhere else that we're not seeing. That code doesn't make sense; check to see if you've consumed the cursor somewhere else in your real code.